# Filters Options for collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called **`Metadatum`** (silly, I know) which has two fields, **`key`** and **`value`**. A key is prefixed with it's type followed by an underscore. The possible types are **`modifier_`**, **`option_`** or  **`uom_`** (unit of measure) which is then followed by a user-defined key. For example: `uom_ounce`.

I define the types in a class method of `Metadatum`:

```
def self.types
    { 'Modifier' => 'modifier', 'Option' => 'option', 'Unit of Measure' => 'uom'}
end
```

I parse out my static types from the user-defined keys using this instance method:

```
def parsed_key
    self.key.split('_', 2).last
end
```

My goal is to present a select box for each type. Here's how I'm trying to do accomplish it:

```
<% Metadatum.types.each do |type| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :item_metadata do |builder| %>
        <%= cell((builder.label :fk_metadatum_id, type.first),   (builder.collection_select(:fk_metadatum_id, Metadatum.where(["key LIKE ?", "%#{type.last}%"]).first, :id, :parsed_key, options ={:prompt => "- #{type.first}"}) ))%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to render the page in my browser, I get this error message:

```
undefined method `map' for #<Metadatum:0x1c9c68b38>
```

Here's the offending code:

```
Metadatum.where(["key LIKE ?", "%#{type.last}%"]).first, :id, :parsed_key, options ={:prompt => "- #{type.first}"
```

Originally, I had `Metadatum.all` instead and the page rendered, but that isn't the desired result.

Is there a simple way to filter options for a select box?

Comment: Well that was easy. I had to remove ```.first``` from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mindless programming mistake.

I was calling `.first` on the collection. I removed it, and now it works.